# Добавление menuBar

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qmenubar, qaction

Нужно добавить `menuBar` в код(ниже). Не понимаю как это сделать.

````
import ftplib
import sys
import easygui

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QGraphicsOpacityEffect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
# msg = "Введите информацию о сервере"
# fieldNames = ["IP Сервера", "Логин", "Пароль"]
# title = 'FTP' 
# ftp_log = easygui.multpasswordbox(msg, title, fieldNames)
ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.168.0.1', 'Artem','1204')
# ftp.cwd('/disk1_1')


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.ftp_lst()
        self.a()

    def ftp_lst(self):
        self.file_lst = ftp.nlst()
        self.len_file_lst = len(ftp.nlst())
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        positions = [(i,j) for i in range(self.len_file_lst) for j in range(1)]
        for position, name in zip(positions, self.file_lst):
            if name == '':
                continue
            self.button = QPushButton(name)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.button, *position)
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.show()

    def update(self):
        self.ftp_lst()

    def on_click(self):
        a = self.sender()      
        ftp.cwd(f'{ftp.pwd()}/{a.text()}')
        self.update()
        print(ftp.pwd())
        print(a.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс `QMenuBar` предоставляет горизонтальную строку меню.

> QMenu *QMenuBar::`addMenu`(const QString &title)
>
> Добавляет новое QMenu с заголовком в строку меню.
> Строка меню становится владельцем меню. Возвращает новое меню.

Класс `QAction` предоставляет абстрактное действие пользовательского интерфейса,
которое можно вставлять в виджеты.

> void QAction::`triggered`(bool checked = false)
>
> Этот сигнал излучается, когда действие активируется пользователем;
> например, когда пользователь щелкает пункт меню, кнопку на панели инструментов
> или нажимает комбинацию клавиш действия, или когда был вызван trigger().
> Примечательно, что он не генерируется при вызове setChecked() или toggle().
>
> Если действие можно проверить, параметр checked имеет значение true,
> если действие отмечено флажком, или false, если действие не отмечено флажком.

> QAction *QMenu::`addAction`(const QString &text)
>
> Эта удобная функция создает новое действие с текстом.
> Функция добавляет вновь созданное действие в список действий меню и возвращает его.
> QMenu становится владельцем возвращенного QAction.

```
import sys
import ftplib
import easygui

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, QGraphicsOpacityEffect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QApplication, QMenuBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

# msg = "Введите информацию о сервере"
# fieldNames = ["IP Сервера", "Логин", "Пароль"]
# title = 'FTP' 
# ftp_log = easygui.multpasswordbox(msg, title, fieldNames)
ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.168.0.1', 'Artem', '1204')
# ftp.cwd('/disk1_1')


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid = QGridLayout()

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(self)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 766, 26))
        self.file = self.menubar.addMenu('&Опции')
        self.exitAction = QAction(QIcon('cross-exit.ico'), '&Exit', self)
        self.exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        self.exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)
        self.file.addAction(self.exitAction)    
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        
        
        self.ftp_lst()
#        self.a()                                                      # ---
        self.a = None                                                  # +++

    def ftp_lst(self):
        self.file_lst = ftp.nlst()
        self.len_file_lst = len(ftp.nlst())
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
        positions = [(i,j) for i in range(self.len_file_lst) for j in range(1)]
        for position, name in zip(positions, self.file_lst):
            if name == '':
                continue
            self.button = QPushButton(name)
            self.grid.addWidget(self.button, *position)
            self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
#        self.show()

    def update(self):
        self.ftp_lst()

    def on_click(self):
        a = self.sender()      
        ftp.cwd(f'{ftp.pwd()}/{a.text()}')
        self.update()
        print(ftp.pwd())
        print(a.text())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.resize(600, 400)                                             # +
    ex.show()                                                       # +++
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]